# How do I write a Bash script for this scenario?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

I have these files in the directory `home/acs`.

```
TBBN027162G_38d8-2f08-0c40
TBBN027605G_38d8-2f08-1518
TBBN027941G_38d8-2f08-0d1c
TBBN027923G_38d8-2f08-35e4
```

I want to read `TBBN027162G` as `service_id` and `38d8-2f08-0c40` as `mac_address` and then store it into my database. I also want to back up the file for the future reference.

Below is the script I tried to write, still incomplete. I have no idea how to make this work.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/acs/

FILES=*

for f in $FILES
do
    #backup file
    echo "$f" >> /home/suriani/acs/data/mac/maclist

    while read $line
    do
      awk -F '_' '{print $1}' /home/suriani/acs/data/mac/maclist
      #read service_id

      awk -F '_' '{print $2}' /home/suriani/acs/data/mac/maclist
      #read mac_address

    done < /home/suriani/acs/data/mac/maclist

done
```

The output:

```
TBBN027162G
38d8-2f08-0c40
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
TBBN027923G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
38d8-2f08-35e4
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
TBBN027923G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
38d8-2f08-35e4
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
TBBN027923G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
38d8-2f08-35e4
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
TBBN027923G
TBBN027941G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
38d8-2f08-35e4
38d8-2f08-0d1c
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
TBBN027923G
TBBN027941G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
38d8-2f08-35e4
38d8-2f08-0d1c
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
TBBN027923G
TBBN027941G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
38d8-2f08-35e4
38d8-2f08-0d1c
TBBN027162G
TBBN027605G
TBBN027923G
TBBN027941G
38d8-2f08-0c40
38d8-2f08-1518
38d8-2f08-35e4
38d8-2f08-0d1c
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: hi @kos im using mysql

Answer (score 0):

In python

#### In a one- (long-) liner:

```bsh
python3 -c 'data = [l.split("_") for l in open("f").read().splitlines()]; [print("service_id: "+d[0]+",", "mac_address: "+d[1]) for d in data]'
```

where 'f' is the sourcefile, between (double) quotes.

Output:

```
service_id: TBBN027162G mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-0c40
service_id: TBBN027605G mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-1518
service_id: TBBN027941G mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-0d1c
service_id: TBBN027923G mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-35e4
```

#### Written out in a scriptfile:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]

data = [l.split("_") for l in open(f).read().splitlines()]
for d in data:
    print("service_id: "+d[0]+",", "mac_address: "+d[1])
```

- If you prefer the script version, Copy it into an empty file, save it as `extract_data.py`, run it with the file as an argument:

```bsh
    python3 /path/to/extract_data.py /path/to/sourcefile
```

***In detail, "zooming out":***

```
open(f).read().splitlines()
```

reads the file, splits it into lines

```
[l.split("_") for l in open(f).read().splitlines()]
```

creates a list of those lines, split in two sections by the delimiter `_`

```
for d in data:
    print("service_id: "+d[0]+",", "mac_address: "+d[1])
```

finally combines the two sections per line with the strings:

```
service_id:
```

and

```
mac_address:
```

---

### EDIT

Reading multiple (all) files in a directory at once, we need two more lines in the script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os

dr = sys.argv[1]
# list the directory's files, exclude hidden and backup files:
flist = [dr+"/"+f for f in os.listdir(dr) if not any([f.startswith("."), f.endswith("~")])]
# split the lines into sections:
data = sum([[l.split("_") for l in open(f).read().splitlines()] for f in flist], [])
# generate the print command per (split) line, combine it with the naming strings:
[print("service_id: "+d[0]+",", "mac_adrres: "+d[1]) for d in data]
```

Although the script skips hidden files and files, ending with `~`, it assumes the directory only contains readable and valid files.

Use it exactly as the first script, but now only with the *directory* as an argument:

```
python3 /path/to/extract_data.py /path/to/source_directory
```

Example output:

```
service_id: TBBN027162A, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-0c21
service_id: TBBN027605A, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-1534
service_id: TBBN027941A, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-0d8v
service_id: TBBN027923A, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-35e4
service_id: TBBN027162G, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-0c40
service_id: TBBN027605G, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-1518
service_id: TBBN027941G, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-0d1c
service_id: TBBN027923G, mac_adrres: 38d8-2f08-35e4
```

Comment: hi Jacob, if im using ubuntu, can i use the same code?

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer absolutely! try it in a terminal window (as said, replace `'f'` by (the path to) your file, between double quotes. I *am* on Ubuntu :)

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer waitwait, I made a typo: use `"f"` between *double* quotes!!

Comment: how i fix this error {{{Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/acs/*')}}}

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer Ah, I thought you had a single file (*I have file in directory: home/acs*)? Do you have multiple files or a single? To read all files works differently in python, you are using wildcards in a different language :) Let me know!!

Comment: hi jacob, i have multiple file to be read in my directory. sorry for my mistake .please advice

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer see my updated answer.

Comment: hi @Jacob, thanks for details explanation. how can i use mysql to insert this data into database

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer I am afraid I am not a specialist on mysql, but no doubt you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags or ask a question there.

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer The format proposed by Jacob is called CSV (Comma Separated Values), have a look to [MySQL documentation for LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to see how to import a CSV into the database, it's a matter of building a simple query based on the field you want to import

Comment: See other comment!  I changed my mind...  Everyone equal!  *:P  ;-)** (but you got an extra upvote!)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` to create an SQL query:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec awk -F_ '{print "INSERT INTO table (service_id, mac_adress) VALUES (\""$1"\",\""$2"\");"}' {} \;
```

Example output:

```
INSERT INTO table (service_id, mac_adress) VALUES ("TBBN027162G", "38d8-2f08-0c40");
INSERT INTO table (service_id, mac_adress) VALUES ("TBBN027605G", "38d8-2f08-1518");
INSERT INTO table (service_id, mac_adress) VALUES ("TBBN027941G", "38d8-2f08-0d1c");
INSERT INTO table (service_id, mac_adress) VALUES ("TBBN027923G", "38d8-2f08-35e4");
```

Or a more complete version:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/suriani/acs/data/mac/maclist -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.bak" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do

    # create the queries
    queries=$(awk -F_ 'print "INSERT INTO table (service_id, mac_adress) VALUES (\""$1"\",\""$2"\");"' "$file");

    # fire the queries, echo is a sample output
    echo "$queries"

    # if database update is ok, move the file
    # mv "$file" "/home/suriani/acs/data/mac/maclist/$file.bak"
done
```

Comment: hi @A.B,thank you. i try to run your script but get this error **Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]**

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer ups, only a typo =)

Comment: I like the idea, +1 however it seems like OP needs a sequence of `INSERT INTO` rather then a sequence of `UPDATE`

Comment: @kos, you're right updated

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Sorry!  I normally do this only for questions that have only one answer...  So instead of putting the same comment under yours, I've removed the offending one!  **:P  ;-)**

Comment: hi @A.B, can i know what is the meaning of this line `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do` . if i would like to read line by line for example `while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n $line ]];` how do i add them

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer Why line by line? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/3644902

Comment: @A.B i need to select a username and password based on service id and store username, password, service id and mac address in my table.

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer You should ask a new question for that. Be fair, only one question per question ;) And ask questions is good for your reputation.

Comment: @enthusiasticengineer As you're a reputation < 15 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)